# Custom routes and i18n

Tags: zend-framework

I am very experienced with the CakePHP framework but am checking out the Zend Framework for an application that will receive massive traffic.

I need to set up some non-standard routes and add in i18n (url-based) and have seen some parts of the reference documentation that refer to this, and creating Registry keys etc, but I've not found any information about how to do this practically - how do I "Put it into the registry with the key Zend_Translate." what file should I even be doing this in?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your best will be to do it in the Bootstrap file, so you can have the translation object in all of your application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I'm still unsure what I need to do to achieve what I want. Essentially, I want urls in the form /:locale/xxx to map through to a specific controller and action, and for that locale to be utilised by all translations in the app. Do I add it in application/bootstrap.php? I think I know how to add routes, but don't know how to get access to the router to call addRoute on it. Note, I am using the latest version and the bootstrap recommended by the quickstart guide whereby the contents of the bootstrap.php file is a class called Bootstrap.php

Comment: No worries, got it:

$router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();

Comment: Yea that's the way to do it, althought if you are using the bootstrap, then you should use something like: $this->bootstrap('frontController'); $front = $this->getResource('frontController');